# String en java, ¿es más eficiente crear o asignar?

Tags: java

Imaginemos que tengo un `String` al que voy a asignarle un valor repetidamente dentro de un bucle, ¿qué sería más eficiente declararlo previamente y asignarle valor en cada interacción o hacerlo directamente dentro de cada iteración?

**Ejemplo A:**

```
String temp;
for (...) {
   temp = algo;

   // hacer algo
}
```

**Ejemplo B:**

```
for (...) {
   String temp = algo;

   // hacer algo
}
```

Comment: El mejor caso es el Ejemplo B. Esto se debe a la inmutabilidad de las cadenas en Java: siempre se creará una nueva instancia de `str` al comienzo de su ciclo y tendrá que descartarse al final. En esta [pregunta del sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803674/declaring-variables-inside-or-outside-of-a-loop) lo deja mucho más claro.

Comment: desde mi punto de vista es mejor la opcion **B** si vas a asignarle mismos valores , por el contrario en la opcion **A** hay redundancia

Answer (score 10, accepted):

En principio las buenas prácticas nos dicen que lo ideal es que las variables tengan **el menor alcance (*scope*) posible**, para evitar efectos indeseados, así que en igualdad de condiciones es recomendable declarar las variables dentro del bucle.

En temas de rendimiendo, el compilador de Java lo suficientemente listo como para que el declarar la variable dentro o fuera tenga el mismo coste, así que no es un parámetro a tener en cuenta.

Hay un caso en el que yo recomendaría declarar fuera, pero es la excepción:

```
for (...) {
    String s=calcularValor();
    ... //operaciones con s
};
```

La función `calcularValor` **siempre** devuelve el mismo valor. Si el cálculo es una operación costosa (leer un fichero, por ejemplo), es preferible usarla una vez, aunque luego no usemos la variable fuera del bucle.

Comment: Coincido contigo. creo que es la mejor opción.

Comment: De hecho diria que da igual si `calcularValor`es costosa o es simple, si siempre devuelve lo mismo solo se debe usar una vez.

Comment: @JDev Estoy de acuerdo, pero llamar a un *getter*, donde simplemente accedemos a un atributo, podría ser aceptable dentro del bucle (incluso usando el getter directamente en lugar de una variable)

Answer (score 8):

### Vamos a abordar el problema desde el punto de vista del bytecode

He creado una clase de test, llamada `Test`:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            String temp = String.valueOf(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Si la compilamos y vemos su bytecode usando `javac Test.java` y `javap -c Test.class` respectivamente, veremos:

```
Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test {
  public Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1          // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_0
       1: istore_1
       2: iload_1
       3: sipush        1000
       6: if_icmpge     20
       9: iload_1
      10: invokestatic  #2          // Method java/lang/String.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/String;
      13: astore_2
      14: iinc          1, 1
      17: goto          2
      20: return
}
```

Ahora, cambiemos el código de `Test`:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            temp = String.valueOf(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Y volvamos a ver el bytecode resultante:

```
Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test {
  public Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1              // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_0
       1: istore_2
       2: iload_2
       3: sipush        1000
       6: if_icmpge     20
       9: iload_2
      10: invokestatic  #2              // Method java/lang/String.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/String;
      13: astore_1
      14: iinc          2, 1
      17: goto          2
      20: return
}
```

Lo único que cambia es el orden de variables. En concreto, de `temp` y la `i` de dentro del bucle. Es decir, **el bytecode es el mismo**. Sabiendo esto, lo mejor es seguir las mejores prácticas, que como ya se ha comentado es reducir el ámbito de la variable en cuestión lo más posible. La mejor opción es B.